# encorporating tikz tree in a figure environment messes up "landscape" option

Tags: floats, tikz-trees, landscape

I have a large `tikz` tree that I can only display properly if I turn around my page to `landscape`. Doing so is not a problem: The `\begin{landscape}` and `\end{landscape}` commands do that fine.

However, I want to include my tree in my list of figures, so I decided to place a `figure` environment around it. That messes up the landscape -- the page is rotated to portrait again.

I do not quite understand where's the problem...

Here's a code snippet:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{sectsty} 
\pagestyle{fancyplain} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,shapes}

\begin{document}

\section{start}
here comes the text in portrait mode.

\begin{landscape}
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=0.9cm, sibling distance=11cm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=0.9cm, sibling distance=12cm]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=0.9cm, sibling distance=6cm]
\tikzstyle{level 4}=[level distance=1.1cm, sibling distance=3cm]
\tikzstyle{level 5}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=2cm]
\tikzstyle{level 6}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=2cm]
\tikzstyle{bag} = [rectangle, text width=5em, text centered, draw,]
\tikzstyle{Group Name} = [circle, minimum height=8pt, minimum width=8pt,  inner sep=0pt, draw]
\tikzstyle{choice} = [circle, minimum width=8pt, fill, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{end_good} = [rectangle, rounded corners, text width=7em,text centered, draw, text=green]
\tikzstyle{end_bad} = [rectangle, rounded corners, text width=7em,text centered, draw, text=red]
\tikzstyle{end} = [rectangle, rounded corners, text width=10em,text centered, draw]

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=down,child anchor=north]
\node[end]{blah}
   child {node[Group Name]{B}
         child {node[bag]{blah}
               child {node[Group Name]{A}
                     child {node[bag]{blah}
                           child{node[end_bad]{blah}
                           }
                     }
                     child {node[bag]{blah}
                           child{node[end_good]{blah}
                           }
                     }
               }  
               child {node[Group Name]{B}
                     child {node[bag]{blah}
                           child{node[end_bad]{blah}
                           }
                     }
                     child {node[bag]{blah}
                           child{node[end_good]{blah}
                           }
                     }
               }  
         }
         child {node[bag]{blah}
               child {node[Group Name]{A}
                     child {node[bag]{blah}
                           child{node[end_good]{blah}
                           }
                     }
                     child {node[bag]{blah}
                           child{node[end_good]{blah}
                           }
                     }
                 }
                 child {node[Group Name]{B}
                     child {node[bag]{blah}
                           child{node[end_bad]{blah}
                           }
                     }
                     child {node[bag]{blah}
                           child{node[end_good]{blah}
                           }
                     }
                 }
         }
                }                          
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=down,child anchor=north]
\node[end]{more blah}
   child {node[Group Name]{B}
         child {node[bag]{more blah}
               child {node[Group Name]{A}
                     child {node[bag]{more blah}
                           child{node[end_bad]{more blah}
                           }
                     }
                     child {node[bag]{more blah}
                           child{node[end_good]{more blah}
                           }
                     }
               }  
               child {node[Group Name]{B}
                     child {node[bag]{more blah}
                           child{node[end_good]{more blah}
                           }
                     }
                     child {node[bag]{more blah}
                           child{node[end_good]{more blah}
                           }
                     }
               }  
         }
         child {node[bag]{more blah}
               child {node[Group Name]{A}
                     child {node[bag]{more blah}
                           child{node[end_bad]{more blah}
                           }
                     }
                     child {node[bag]{more blah}
                           child{node[end_good]{more blah}
                           }
                     }
                 }
                 child {node[Group Name]{B}
                     child {node[bag]{more blah}
                           child{node[end_good]{more blah}
                           }
                     }
                     child {node[bag]{more blah}
                           child{node[end_good]{more blah}
                           }
                     }
                 }
         }
                }                          
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

Assumptions:
Here go some assuptions

\begin{itemize}
\item blah blah
\item blah
\item blah
\end{itemize}


\end{landscape}
go on in portrait mode.

\end{document}
```

Interestingly, the Assumptions that were supposed to be posted under the tree (still in landscape mode), are in fact in landscape mode, while the tree is not.

Is there any way to make the tree be in landscape mode within a figure environment?

Thanks for any advice!

---

EDIT

I switched to `\usepackage{pdflscape}` and also included the assumptions within the figure. The `tikz`-code now looks like this:

```
 \begin{figure}
\begin{landscape}


\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=0.9cm, sibling distance=11cm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=0.9cm, sibling distance=12cm]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=0.9cm, sibling distance=6cm]
\tikzstyle{level 4}=[level distance=1.1cm, sibling distance=3cm]
\tikzstyle{level 5}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=2cm]
\tikzstyle{level 6}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=2cm]
\tikzstyle{bag} = [rectangle, text width=5em, text centered, draw,]
\tikzstyle{Group Name} = [circle, minimum height=8pt, minimum width=8pt,  inner sep=0pt, draw]
\tikzstyle{choice} = [circle, minimum width=8pt, fill, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{end_good} = [rectangle, rounded corners, text width=7em,text centered, draw, text=green]
\tikzstyle{end_bad} = [rectangle, rounded corners, text width=7em,text centered, draw, text=red]
 \tikzstyle{end} = [rectangle, rounded corners, text width=10em,text centered, draw]

 \begin{tikzpicture}[grow=down,child anchor=north]
\node[end]{blah}
   child {node[Group Name]{B}
         child {node[bag]{blah}
               child {node[Group Name]{A}
                     child {node[bag]{blah}
                           child{node[end_bad]{blah}
                           }
                     }
                     child {node[bag]{blah}
                           child{node[end_good]{blah}
                           }
                     }
               }  
               child {node[Group Name]{B}
                     child {node[bag]{blah}
                           child{node[end_bad]{blah}
                           }
                     }
                     child {node[bag]{blah}
                           child{node[end_good]{blah}
                           }
                     }
               }  
         }
         child {node[bag]{blah}
               child {node[Group Name]{A}
                     child {node[bag]{blah}
                           child{node[end_good]{blah}
                           }
                     }
                     child {node[bag]{blah}
                           child{node[end_good]{blah}
                           }
                     }
                 }
                 child {node[Group Name]{B}
                     child {node[bag]{blah}
                           child{node[end_bad]{blah}
                           }
                     }
                     child {node[bag]{blah}
                           child{node[end_good]{blah}
                           }
                     }
                 }
         }
                }                          
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=down,child anchor=north]
\node[end]{more blah}
   child {node[Group Name]{B}
         child {node[bag]{more blah}
               child {node[Group Name]{A}
                     child {node[bag]{more blah}
                           child{node[end_bad]{more blah}
                           }
                     }
                     child {node[bag]{more blah}
                           child{node[end_good]{more blah}
                           }
                     }
               }  
               child {node[Group Name]{B}
                     child {node[bag]{more blah}
                           child{node[end_good]{more blah}
                           }
                     }
                     child {node[bag]{more blah}
                           child{node[end_good]{more blah}
                           }
                     }
               }  
         }
         child {node[bag]{more blah}
               child {node[Group Name]{A}
                     child {node[bag]{more blah}
                           child{node[end_bad]{more blah}
                           }
                     }
                     child {node[bag]{more blah}
                           child{node[end_good]{more blah}
                           }
                     }
                 }
                 child {node[Group Name]{B}
                     child {node[bag]{more blah}
                           child{node[end_good]{more blah}
                           }
                     }
                     child {node[bag]{more blah}
                           child{node[end_good]{more blah}
                           }
                     }
                 }
         }
                }                          
;
\end{tikzpicture}


Some assumptiona:
\begin{itemize}
\item 
\item blah    
\item blah    
\end{itemize}


\end{landscape}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

However, it is still showing the figure in portrait mode and hence only half of it... Are there any more suggestions?

Comment: Try `\usepackage{pdflscape}` instead of `\usepackage{lscape}` (and put the Assumptions within the `figure` environment).

Comment: Your figure is quite large and when put in a float it forces a float page which resets quite some values. Either use sidewaysfigure from the rotating package, or set the caption with `\captionof{figure}{Some text}`.

Comment: If the assumptions belong with the tree, then they need to go inside the `figure`. `figure` creates a float. You are telling LaTeX that this is a distinct chunk of stuff which it should move as it likes (i.e. 'float' to what it thinks is the best position, according to its algorithm). So you assumptions won't stay with the tree if the tree floats but the assumptions don't. If you don't use the `figure` environment (or another float environment), there's no problem, but otherwise, you will have trouble at some point even if it just so happens that LaTeX keeps the things together for now.

Comment: `\tikzstyle{}` is deprecated, by the way. Note that `forest` creates trees which are, in most cases, more compact.

Comment: @Marjin: I did as you suggested and posted the new code. However, it does not solve the problem...

Comment: @cfr: I added the assumptions into the `figure` environment, as you suggested. As this is the only tree I need in my whole thesis, I would appreciate not having to learn how to handle the `forest` package. However, if it's inevitable, I might go for it since there's no real way to keep the trees readable if I make them smaller...

Comment: @PikkuKatja in your new MWE you have put the landscape environment inside of your figure (whereas in your original MWE the landscape is outside of the figure). When I try  the order landscape-figure-tikzpicture-tikzpicture-assumptions-end figure-end landscape (and `pdflscape` as package) then I get 1 portrait page, one landscape page with the trees rotated and the assumptions (also rotated) under the second tree, and then another portrait page.

Comment: @PikkuKatja Ulrike Fischer already gave you the answer. Either use the `rotating` package or don't use a float at all and create the caption, if you need one, using `capt-of` or `caption` which provide `\captionof...`. Floats float. You can't put `landscape` inside one and have things work right.

Comment: thanks for the advice! I tried that and included `\captionof{figure}[Decision Tree]{Decision Tree}` within the `tikzpicture`. But it says "Missing \endgroup inserted."  Could it be that I still have to define that a `tikzpicture` is accepted as a style (as the package documentation says, style is either `table` or `figure` or something I need to define...:http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/capt-of/capt-of.pdf)